# MVC 5 ASP.Net Switching Language

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.net MVC 5 application that has worked for years correctly.

Recently switching between French and English language has stopped working. It is deployed on Windows Azure.

The switching of the language still works fine on the development machine and uses the following code:

```cs
        public ActionResult SetLanguage(string culture)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            // Validate input
            culture = MSP.Services.CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(culture);
            // Save culture in a cookie
            HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
            if (cookie != null)
                cookie.Value = culture;   // update cookie value
            else
            {
                cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
                cookie.Value = culture;
            }
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);


            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { message = $"The language has now been set to {culture}" });
        }
```

Not sure if something has changed on Windows Azure?

Comment: By any chance, are your cookies set correctly with `SameSite` and `Secure` Flags? Chrome for example removes cookies which miss these properties. You should inspect your cookies on the client if they are what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You may well be onto something here. I tried the application using Firefox instead of Microsoft Edge or Google Chrome and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I added the following line just before the cookie is added:

```cs
cookie.Secure = true;
```

It's now working on all browsers.

Turns out this is a required change made by the Chromium Browsers that is being gradually rolled out since the summer of 2020.  IE cookies should be secure.

Comment: The why [https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032) :)